# PostgreSQL jsonb type with jpa attribute converter

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I've got table with column of type "jsonb".
In entity I set type String for this column with attribute converter:

```
@Convert(converter = JSONBConverter.class)
@Column(name = STATE_COLUMN, nullable = false)
private String getState() {
    return state;
}
```

And my converter looks like:

```
@Converter
public class JSONBConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        PGobject result = new PGobject();
        result.setType("json");
        try {
            result.setValue(attribute);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to set jsonb value");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Object dbData) {
        if (dbData instanceof PGobject) {
            return ((PGobject) dbData).getValue();
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

I got dialect set to: `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`

I thought it was gonna work. But I get an error with:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Nieznana warto�� Types:
>   1�936�628�443

As I debugged it gets `targetSqlType` in `PgPreparedStatement` class setObject method 1936628443 - what indicates on Object type which is taken from my AttributeConverter class which is assigned in `SqlTypeDescriptorRegistry` class.

I've got:

postgresql version `42.2.1`

hibernate version `5.2.10.Final`

Answer (score 3):

`AttributeConverter` + `json/jsonb` do not play well together because you need to bind the JSON object at the `PreparedStatement` level.

You have to declare a Hibernate Type to get JSONB working.

See [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) for a detailed tutorial of how you can do that.

Comment: is this still the case with Hibernate 6.1 support for JSONB?